# tailwindcss gets automatically installed when i am creating a new create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs

I was following this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcHssmXnU8E&list=PL0mGKoXn4Bs3DgaOsXLZLpQx0TnN5eCqS&index=7&t=3740s](https://stackoverflow.com).
When i was trying to install tailwindcss i skipped the 1st step that is

`npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer^9`  
instead

i dowloaded the tailwindcss, postcss and autoprefixer using below commands.

`npm install tailwindcss, postcss and autoprefixer`

After that i followed the all steps given in the tutorial which are as follows:

2. npm install@craco/craco
3. changes in package.json

```
`{
        "scripts":{
           "start":"craco start",
           "build":"craco build",
           "test":"craco test",
           "eject":"react-scripts eject"
         },
     }`
```

4. craco.config.js is in root of our project and added the 'tailwindcss' and 'autoprefixer'as POSTCSS plugins
   and added the below code in it

```
`module.exports{
style:{
    postcss:{
        plugins:[
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer'),
           ],
       },
},
}`
```

5. generate tailwindcss using below command
   `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init`
6. copy
   `purge:['./src/**/*. {js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html']`
   in Tailwind.config.js
7. add text below text in the index.css

```
`@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;`
```

`8) npm i` 
`9) npm run start`

But the issue comes when tailwindcss was not applied to my project's index.css. That' when i decided to uninstall these packages.

But even after uninstalling these packages, whenever i am trying to use below command

`npx create-react-app ./`  
to create a new react project, after execution of this command i see tailwindcss, postcss and autoprefixer packages in the package-lock.json and in the node_modules folder.

I tried all the option given on the web but not able to find the solution. In the end i tried to uninstall Node.js using this link

```
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows][1]
```

but even after that

`npx create-react-app ./`

is installing the dependencies of tailwindcss, poscss, autoprefixer packages by default.

I just want to remove these dependencies so that i would be able to create a new fresh react app using create-react-app.

Any help would be great in this regard.

Comment: If you want to react app, use this instead. It's more light and easy to use https://vitejs.dev/

Comment: No i just want to remove the dependencies which are by default installing when i am running create-react-app